# how to implement pagination in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, pagination

I am new to phonegap. I wish to implement `pagination` functionality using phonegap. 
I wish to keep one `div` and above it should be page numbers. On click of each page number, div contents should change.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some frameworks like Jquery mobile. What I use is [Jquery Mobile Multiple Pages](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/pages-multi-page/index.html)

HTML Code

```
Start of first page

<div data-role="page" id="foo">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

```
page 1 end
Start of second page
```

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Like this you can put many pages in one html.

For this Refer [**Link**](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/pages/)

Another Option Is swiping from one page to another page. For this refer [**Link**](http://phonegaptutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/phonegap-pagination-tutorial-using.html)